# Transfer Ownership of a contract from one adress to another problem

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, nft, address.transfer

I am Digital Desginer and i wanted to sell my Designs as of NFT, so that I found a guy to write me an smart contract on polygon network for me to able to publish my arts on  blockchain . so After he wrote the contract we minted 1000 of my arts and then he transfered ownership of the contract to my  matic adress, For now  i am the owner of the contract.  Is it possible for him to revert contract back to his adress, or is it possible to rug pull if i be successfull , will i be the only owner of the contract ? can he touch it in any bad way

---

This is the Contract Adress , you can check it , Thanks for enlighten me

https://polygonscan.com/address/0x52e6cd20f5fca56da5a0e489574c92af118b8188#code

Comment: This depends on the code, please share the code

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question lies in the contract. Which you did not provide.

Logically  ,according the **proper functioning of ERC721** (*which i will assume is the standard of your NFT*), if he **gave you ownership** then normally he **cannot get the ownership back unless you willingly give it to him**.

Now he may have written malicious code, but **without the code**, we cannot say anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Ownership contract made by OpenZeppelin, that you can find  just below with the github repo :
[OpenZeppelin Docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/ownership)

[Github repository file](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/a5ed318634016a25be4000ee07044a31f363e60c/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L4)

If ownership has been transferred to your Matic address, then the original creator should not have the ability to revert ownership back to himself or "rug pull" without your explicit permission.

As the owner, you are the only one with the power to perform privileged actions on the contract, such as transferring ownership again. The contract's security depends on the OpenZeppelin Ownership standards, which are widely regarded as secure and robust. And it would be better if you could share the smart contract itself because what I explained here is based on the fact that OZ is employed.